# How to override object fields and made IDE see it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete, webstorm

I have some class with some State property, and I format the State's fields via some function:

```
function DoMagic(prototypeObj: any) : any;
```

So, funcion "DoMagic" turns object from:

```
const Foo = {
    ID: -1,
    Name: '',
    Something: [1,2,3]
}
```

to

```
const Bar = {
    ID: {
        get Value(){return Foo.ID;},
    },
    Name: {
        get Value(){return Foo.ID;},
    },
    Something: {
        0: {get Value(){return Foo.Something[0]} },
        1: {get Value(){return Foo.Something[1]} },
        2: {get Value(){return Foo.Something[2]} },
    }
};
```

It works fine, but I want to made WebStorm's autocomplete offer Bar's properties instead of Foo, when Foo is a class property.

If I do something like

```
type ClassState = {
    ID: number;
    Name: string;
    Something: number[]
}
class Class1{
    State: ClassState = {
        ID: -1,
        Name: '',
        Something: [1,2,3],
    };
    constructor(){
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'State', DoMagic(this.State))
    }
}
let instance = new Class1();
```

And there is no illusion: intellisense shows me, of course, ClassState's properties.

The closest way I get it - define some custom types and declare own "interface" like this:

```
class TypesBase {
    protected _Value: any;
    get Value():any {return this._Value};
}
class TypeInt extends TypesBase{
    get Value() : number {return this._Value};
}
class TypeString extends TypesBase{
    get Value() : string {return this._Value};
}
class TypeArray<T> extends TypesBase{
    get Value() : T[] {return this._Value};
}
class Class2 {
    State = {
        ID: new TypeInt(),
        Name: new TypeString(),
        Something: new TypeArray<number>(),
    };
    StateData = {
        ID: -1,
        Name: '',
        Something: [1,2,3],
    };
    constructor(){
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'State', DoMagic(this.StateData))
    }
}
let inst2 = new Class2();
```

It works fine for simple fields like `inst2.ID.Value`, but `inst2.Something[0].Value` - doesn't, and, anyway, I want it to work deeper.

Is it possible at all?

// ADDED
Thanks, jcalz, this way is more cleaner

```
type Magic<T> = {[K in keyof T]: any | {Value: T[K]}};
class Class2 {
    State: Magic<ClassState> = {
        ID: -1,
        Name: '',
        Something: [1,2,3],
    };
...
```

But how to make it work for deeper levels? Like:

```
inst2.Something[0].Value
inst2.Something[0].DeeperLevelObject.Value
```

Comment: You might want to correct your tags. Intellisense is Microsoft's implementation of code completion. Intellisense does not exists in Webstorm.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking for.  If this is a question about the type system, I'd say define `type Magic<T> = {[K in keyof T]: {Value: T[K]}` and then define the type of `Class1`'s `state` property to be `Magic<ClassState>`.  But I think this isn't enough of a [mcve] to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

Need to declare types:

```
type Simple<T> = {Value: T};
type MagicArray<T, U> = {
    [Key: number]: Simple<U>;
    Value: T
}

type Magic<T> = Simple<T>
    &
    {   readonly [K in keyof T]:
            T[K] extends (infer ElementType)[] ? MagicArray<T[K], ElementType>:
            T[K] extends object ? Magic<T[K]> :
            Simple<T[K]>
    }
```

Using:

```
type ClassState2 = {
    Field1: number;
    Field2: string;
};
type ClassState = {
    ID: number;
    Name: string;
    SomeArr: number[];
    SomeObj: ClassState2;
    SomeObjArr: ClassState2[];
};

const SomeState : Magic<ClassState> = null;

//now SomeState can get autocomplete with proper types:
SomeState.Value; 
SomeState.ID.Value;
SomeState.SomeArr[0].Value;
SomeState.SomeObjArr[0].Field1.Value;
...
```